Why isn't `key in object` enough to pacify TS?
type LanguageKey =
    | 'c++'
    | 'python'
    | 'javascript'
    | 'typescript';

class Test {
    languages: Partial<Record<LanguageKey, string>> = {};
    
    needsString(str: string): void { console.log(str);}

    useLangKey(langKey: LanguageKey): void {
        if (langKey in this.languages) {
            const language = this.languages[langKey];
            this.needsString(language); // <-- "'string | undefined' is not assignable to 'string'" ??
        }
    }
}

TS complains on the marked line that "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.".  Shouldn't the test langKey in this.languages be enough?
TS playground link

It can be undefined as shown in this playground link. Your check should be checking for undefined, not key presence, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll... well it looks like existing answers cover this. If not, what's missing?

Consider:
const foo = {
  bar: undefined
}

console.log('bar' in foo); // equals 'true'

Because you used Partial you made undefined valid value for properties in this object.
The check you'll want is:
if (this.languages[langKey] !== undefined) {


Thank you. Is there a construct different from Partial that would say 'keys may be missing, but those who are present obey the Record type'?

I'm sure that there's some crazy typescript construct that gets you there, but not sure myself.The specific question you asked is answered though

^ @OfekShilon Yes, see the compiler option exactOptionalPropertyTypes (example)

That compiler setting does indeed represent that situation but it does so for all types everywhere… and even if you use it, you can’t do what you’re doing with an in check on a union of keys. TS won’t recognize that as a narrowing.


How are you guaranteeing that the record exists? Undefined is neither in String nor LanguageKey, and I think that's what it's complaining about.
You can fix this by adding an empty check
...
const language = this.languages[langKey];
if(!language) throw Error();
this.needsString(language);
...


But langKey is declared to be of type LanguageKey, as far as TS is concerned it can't be undefined. (hope I understood what you mean)
